# how to convert this query in yii framework model

Tags: php, sql, yii

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, u.score, 
(SELECT COUNT(ownerId) FROM post p WHERE p.ownerId = u.id) AS totalPost 
FROM users u 
ORDER BY u.score DESC, totalPost DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao

Comment: Just remember as well to make use of the web debug bar which will show you the queries being executed. This can really help as you are writing your code as you can see how close/far away you are from what you want.

Comment: What do you mean "convert"? Do you just want to execute it straight up? Or do you have a User model and you want to query these Users using CDBCriteria?

Answer (score 4):

```
$sql = "SELECT u.id, u.username, u.score, ".
   "(SELECT COUNT(ownerId) FROM post p WHERE p.ownerId = u.id) AS totalPost ".
   "FROM users u ".
   "ORDER BY u.score DESC, totalPost DESC ".
   "LIMIT 10";
$command=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
$results=$command->query();
```

or if you have a User model (I *think* this will work - I didn't test either of these ;)

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select = "t.id, t.username, t.score, (SELECT COUNT(ownerId) FROM post p WHERE p.ownerId = t.id) AS totalPost";
$criteria->order = "u.score DESC, totalPost DESC";
$criteria->limit = "10";
$results = User::model()->findAll($criteria); // this returns an array of User models
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested it. But it could work like this

```
$user = User::model()
      ->with('post')
      ->findAll(
          array(
            'select'=>array('id','username','score','totalPost'=>'count(ownerId)'),
            'group'=>'id',
            'order'=>'score DESC,totalPost DESC'
          )
      );
```